# How to pass variable in sed command

Tags: sed

How to pass variable as input to sed command instead of file please find the example below. I am trying to use the command but I am not able to pass the variable

```
test=$(I have shell script here which stores the value in test)
```

Now I want to read the variable and deletethe lines where I find the value 'xyz'

Command i tried

```
sed -i /xyz/d “$test”
```

Answer (score 0):

Process your var like this

```
echo "$test" | sed '/xyz/d'
```

Or like this

```
sed '/xyz/d' <<< "$test"
```